# The database action order in different activity

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I have two activities, say they are `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`, the order:

ActivityA  -->  ActivityB

Now both the two activities will read and write the same database, when the `ActivityB` destory, I will save the last status to the database, then when user go back to `ActivityA` I will reload the status form the databse.

However I found that the `read` action in `ActivityA` is always completed before the `write` action in `ActivityB`:

```
class ActivityB{
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        ....
        mDao.update(mItem);
        System.out.println("pro:save:" + mItem.name + ":" + mItem.progress);
//      mDatabase.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}

class ActivityA{
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mLocalDbLoadTask = new LocalDbLoadTask();
        mLocalDbLoadTask.execute(mItem);
    }
    class LocalDbLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Item, Void, Item> {

        @Override
        protected Item doInBackground(Item... Items) {
            Item item = Items[0];
            mItemDao.fill(item);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Item Item) {
            System.out.println("pro:load:" + mItem.name + ":" + mItem.progress);
        }
    }
}
```

I always get:

```
08-19 03:04:45.730    4757-4757/com.kk I/System.out﹕ pro:load:name xx:11
08-19 03:04:46.094    4757-4757/com.kk I/System.out﹕ pro:save:name xx:14
```

Which means that `ActivityA` can not get the latest status of the item(14 in the example) event if the item is updated at `ActivityB`.

What's the problem?

---

update:

After I move the codes for saving from `onDestory` to `onPause` the order is right, but I still get the wrong value sometimes:

```
08-19 03:30:00.170    5330-5330/com.kk I/System.out﹕ pro:save:xx:16
08-19 03:30:00.214    5330-5330/com.kk I/System.out﹕ pro:load:xxx:null
```

As shown `16` is saved in `ActivityB` but `null` is got in `ActivityA`.

Comment: hm... I see different name in the log (`xxx`).  Is it ok?

Comment: It is ok, I modify the real item name. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, problem is activity lifecycle.

> onPause() Called when the system is about to start resuming a previous activity. 
>   onStop()  Called when the activity is no longer visible to the user, because another activity has been resumed and is covering this one.
>   onDestroy()   The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed.

In general, order should be `ActivityB.onPause()` -> `ActivityA.onResume()` -> `ActivityB.onStop()` -> `ActivityB.onDestroy()`. You can check it by placing log calls in `onResume()`, `onPause()` and `onDestroy()` methods.

So, just write changes to the DB in the `onPause()` method of ActivityB.

[Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: Thank you!! That's exactly the problem! You save my life.:)

Comment: Oh, I am sorry but it seems that even the order is right I still got the old data in the `onresume`. Check my update.

Comment: Do you have right order in the log? Can `mDao` write changes not in the moment of call?

Comment: I found it, it is caused by the update logic, nothing to do with the order. Thanks .:)